# Trying to get property of non-object error on single post page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an articles page that displays a loop of every article in my website.  THen I have a single post page which displays the article itself.  I am trying to modify the post page so that recent posts will display in a loop on the sidebar.  I was trying to copy the loop code from the articles page on to my post page but I got an error.

Articles page code (no errors):

```
                <div class="row col-md-12">

                    @if(isset($_REQUEST['searchItem']) && $_REQUEST['searchItem']<>'')

                    @if(isset($msg))

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">

                         <ul>

                            <li><h3>{{ $msg }}</h3></li>

                         </ul>

                    </div>

                    @else

                    @foreach($result as $result)

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="content">

                        <a href="{{$result->url}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($result->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                            <img style="padding: 5px; width:100%; height:218px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$result->thumbnail)}}" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    @endforeach

                    @endif

                    @else

                    @foreach($post as $post)

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="content">

                        <a href="{{$post->url}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                            <img style="padding: 5px; width:100%; height:218px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                   @endforeach

                   @endif

            </div>
```

Code for the single post page:

```
  <div class="container layer1">
    @if(isset($_REQUEST['searchItem']) && $_REQUEST['searchItem']<>'')
                    @if(isset($msg))

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">

                         <ul>

                            <li><h3>{{ $msg }}</h3></li>

                         </ul>

                    </div>

                    @else

    <div class="row"  style="width:25%;float:left;padding-left:5px;">

        <div class="post-content">

            <div class="post-container">

                <h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>

                <p style="color:#888;">{{ date ('M-d-Y',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</p>

       <!--         <p><img src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></p> -->

                <p><?php echo html_entity_decode($post->content); ?></p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row" style="width:25%;float:left;padding-left:5px;">

        <div class="post-content">

            <div class="post-container">
                <div class="container articles-page">

                    <div class="articles-title">

                    </div>      
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>Recent Posts</h3>
                     @foreach($result as $result)
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="content">

                        <a href="{{$result->url}}" class="latest-heading">{{substr(($result->title),0,88)}}..</a>

                            <img style="padding: 5px; width:100%; height:218px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$result->thumbnail)}}" class="img-responsive">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    @endforeach

                    @endif
                    @else
                         @foreach($post as $post)
 error is here =>      <p><a href="{{ $post->url }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a><br>
                        <a href="{{$post->url}}">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a></p>
                      </tr>
                   @endforeach
                   @endif
                    <div class="row col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The error is on this line:

```
                      <p><a href="{{ $post->url }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a><br>
```

Code in controller file:

```
//view post

public function viewpost($url){

  $url ='articles/'.$url;

    if(count(posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first())<>1){

        return redirect()->back();

    }

    return view('viewpost')

    ->with('post', posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first());

}

    //all posts route

    public function allposts(){

    $post=posts::All();

      if(count($post)==0){

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'There are no posts at this moment');

      }

      else{

        return view ('admin-SchoolDir.allposts',array('post' => $post))->with("title","Admin-Allposts");

      }

    }
```

Comment: Post your controller code .

Comment: As I can see you're using something like Laravel, but, are you passing the $post argument to the new view?

Comment: @Salama96 - done, code posted.

Comment: @Asfo - It IS laravel.  I think I am.  Check the code.

Comment: Check the answer @Thomas

Comment: Sorry, the original question didn't have that part but, as as suggestion, try to add the code "beautified" because is more easy to read than just a "copy/pasted" bad styled code... Also, in this case, I can see $post is an array, not an object. So, there might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

The post defined in the viewpost method is an object while you want to use it as an array in your view .

Your code must be like this

```
 public function viewpost($url){

   $url ='articles/'.$url;

   if(count(posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first())<>1){
      return redirect()->back();
    }

   return view('viewpost')->with(['post'=>posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first(),'posts'=>posts::where('url', '=', $url)->get()]);
 }
```

And in your view change

```
 @foreach($post as $post)
 to  
 @foreach($posts as $post)
```

**Edit :**
You dont need to use count over single object to check for existence your code should be like this

```
 public function viewpost($url){

      $url ='articles/'.$url;

      if(!posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first()){
       return redirect()->back();
      }

     return view('viewpost')->with(['post'=>posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first(),'posts'=>posts::where('url', '=', $url)->get()]);
 }
```

Comment: I get an error on your return view line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>'

Comment: Nevermind, copied your code wrong.  Problem is now....the entire article is gone.  All I see is one of my recent pages that has a thumbnail.

Comment: Her eis an example of a LIVE post: https://collegeconnect.ph/articles/6-keys-to-finding-the-right-college-for-you

Comment: I have edited the code as it seems there is no posts that meets your condition so it will redirect back check the code again

Comment: if(!posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first())

Comment: that's what i have changed @Thomas

Comment: still the same.  no change.

Comment: try to dd(posts::where('url', '=', $url)->get()); what do you get ? @Thomas

Comment: do I put that under the if statement?

Comment: put it after       $url ='articles/'.$url; @Thomas

Comment: So it looks like the output is compatible with the code you got only one element satisfying your condition and it is printed under recent posts so the code works well

Comment: It would help if you added punctuation marks in your comments :) But anyways, the problem is, the actual article itself is not being displayed.  There should be 2 columns: the actual article AND the recent posts (there's more than one).

Comment: This is what it should look like.  This is a page, not a post though.  Different view and controller that is managing this page layout. https://collegeconnect.ph/top-engineering-colleges-philippines.  But the layout for the post page will pretty much look the same.

Comment: do you have any ideas?